# Issue with rpy2 handling NA/missing value in dataframe from R to Python

Tags: r, python-2.7, rpy2

I've encounter a problem when using rpy2 package to transform `dataframe` saved in R to Python.

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources'

import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

# define a trivial dataframe in R
ro.r('n = c(1,2)')
ro.r("b = c(NA,'def')")
ro.r("temp_df = data.frame(n,b)")

# the dataframe in R shows missing value in one cell as NA
temp_rdf = ro.r('temp_df')
print(temp_rdf)

  n    b
1 1 <NA>
2 2  def

# yet the transformed Python dataframe replace the missing value with a string
temp_pydf = pandas2ri.ri2py(temp_rdf)
print(temp_pydf)

     n    b
1  1.0  def
2  2.0  def
```

I did some search and found this post [Rpy2 pandas2ri.ri2py() is converting NA values to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666458/rpy2-pandas2ri-ri2py-is-converting-na-values-to-integers). It explains why but doesn't provide a solution to this. I want to have Null values in Python for those NA in R dataframe. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Updates:
http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/rinterface.html

Above link may have useful help on some settings.  If you find "NA " (include the space" and go to the second hit. There is one that looks like it relates to your NA problem.

Original post:
assuming "def" as shown in your output is coming in as a string, you could replace it with a string that you are confident is not a value in your data and then use this in lieu of the NA value that is not coming in:

This sample code illustrates the concept.

```
x = "def"
type(x)
x = x.replace("def", "NA")
x
```

Looking at the problem that your source has two rows that both say 'def' one where it came from the data and another where NA converted to def:

1. Convert 'def' to something else in R
2. bring in your data
3. now 'def' means NA
4. use it as such or convert it to something you can live with

Is this a problem you encounter often?

1. if so, create a test function to check your data for 'def'
2. if found replace with something crazy you know the data will not have like: my_crazy_replacementValue
3. replace "def" with your desired stand-in for NA
4. replace my_crazy_replacementValue with "def"

In Python, the most common value for NA, I think is None.
Unfortuantely, you cannot replace a value with None using:

```
string.replace()
```

It seems reasonable that there should be a better answer:  a "Pythonic" way of converting a specified value in a data frame to None.  I have to review Pandas -> data frames when I get a chance and then I may log back in and edit this paragraph (or maybe someone else will beat me to it).  Hoping the above might help you in the interim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are many RData files that contain dataframe and I want to load and process them in Python. The example is just for showing the problem.  I am looking for a solution in Python environment only and not using R to pre-process data.

Comment: I am new to this too.  So forgive me if this isn't what you are looking for.  Once the library corrupts your data, if "def" is being presented for two different rows (one that was originally "def" and one that was originally "NA") then you lose precision.  There is no way to fix that in Python after the fact.  The only answer that strikes me but I can't guide you in building it:  use Python file operations to loop through the files correcting def to a temp value.  Then use Data frame operations to clean the result once back in Python.  I must defer to others with more experience beyond that.

Comment: Thanks for actively participating in this discussion TMWP. I am really surprised by how pandas2ri.ri2py handles NA in R dataframe. A natural way  is filling them as Null instead of some value in its Factor. I wish there is a simple way to walk around by setting some magic parameters in rpy2 or by writing rpy2 low-level function.

Comment: Having a very busy week, so answered you based solely on your post and my knowledge going into it.  Found a few spare minutes and checked out your link to rpy2.  Then I tried a simple google search based on "rpy2 default NA" (or something like that, I lifted my keywords from the description on your rpy2 page.  That yielded this link (which if you search for "NA " (must have space after it) using find on the page, and go to the 2nd hit, you will find a topic about a setting for the characters to replace NA with.  See if this helps:  http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/rinterface.html