# rpy2 R->Python data.frame: bad NA and custom converter

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, rpy2

At the moment I'm getting my feet wet with with the `rpy2` package (it's rather cool).

But I'm running in a similar issue as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967536/rpy2-issue-with-converting-df-back-to-pandas), where the type conversion between an R data.frame and a python pandas dataframe is rather messy:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

# float -> NaN
# int -> -2147483648
# Strings -> None
# Bool -> int

ro.r(
    """
        f <- function() {
              return(data.frame(int = c(4L, NA),
                     float = c(1.2, NA),
                     chr = c("A", NA),
                     bool = c(TRUE, FALSE)))
        }
        f()
    """
)

r_f = ro.globalenv["f"]
res = r_f()

with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    pd_from_r_df = ro.conversion.rpy2py(res)

print(pd_from_r_df)
```

results in:

```
python -u "/workspace/SLW/Python_examples/MWE_2.py"
          int  float   chr  bool
1           4    1.2     A     1
2 -2147483648    NaN  None     0
```

As you can see the integer gets blown up and the boolean turned into an integer.
Since this feels like such an ordinary case, I'm sure a lot of people already ran into it and maybe designed their own custom converter like advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993133/10020441). Do you maybe have the code of such an converter for me? So I can start with something in my hands, since at the moment I have no clue how to go about writing my own custom converter. Maybe in the long run such an converter could become a part of the `rpy2` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple, completely custom converter from R to pandas DataFrame:

```py
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter, get_conversion
from rpy2 import rinterface as ri
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.rinterface_lib import na_values

import pandas as pd

# create your own rules for df columns
df_rules = ro.default_converter

@df_rules.rpy2py.register(ri.IntSexpVector)
def to_int(obj):
    return [int(v) if v != na_values.NA_Integer else pd.NA for v in obj]


@df_rules.rpy2py.register(ri.FloatSexpVector)
def to_float(obj):
    return [float(v) if v != na_values.NA_Real else pd.NA for v in obj]


@df_rules.rpy2py.register(ri.StrSexpVector)
def to_str(obj):
    return [str(v) if v != na_values.NA_Character else pd.NA for v in obj]


@df_rules.rpy2py.register(ri.BoolSexpVector)
def to_bool(obj):
    return [bool(v) if v != na_values.NA_Logical else pd.NA for v in obj]

# define the top-level converter
def toDataFrame(obj):
    cv = get_conversion() # get the converter from current context
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {str(k): cv.rpy2py(obj[i]) for i, k in enumerate(obj.names)}
    )

# associate the converter with R data.frame class
df_rules.rpy2py_nc_map[ri.ListSexpVector].update({"data.frame": toDataFrame})


# code in OP
ro.r(
    """
        f <- function() {
              return(data.frame(int = c(4L, NA),
                     float = c(1.2, NA),
                     chr = c("A", NA),
                     bool = c(TRUE, FALSE)))
        }
        f()
    """
)

r_f = ro.globalenv["f"]
res = r_f()

with localconverter(df_rules): # use the defined rules here
    pd_from_r_df = res

print(pd_from_r_df)
```

This prints

```
    int  float   chr   bool
0     4    1.2     A   True
1  <NA>    NaN  <NA>  False
```

So it's not perfect: R's `float` and `bool` NA values are not capturable by the custom converter (at least in the way I've implemented here) but `int` and `str` are working as intended.

Also, it may not be the fastest solution as I believe `padas2ri` module uses numpy's buffer copy mechanism, but atm I don't know how to deal with the NAs in such conversion.